# Is there a way to sort alphabetically the env in C? ( env | sort )

Tags: arrays, c, linux, environment-variables

For my OS class I have to create a terminal with different commands.

One task is to implement pipes.

I want to implement a `( env | sort )` command.

Is it possible? If yes, can someone help me?

The code for it is in the last `else if(!strcmp(arr[0], "env")&& !strcmp(arr[1],"|") && arr[2]!="\0")`

The code is larger but i posted just the part that interest me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX 256

char *comd = NULL;
size_t sizeLine = 0;

int i;
char *param;
char *arr[MAX];

/*From main() -> run() -> spawn child to run commands*/
void run(){
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid != 0) {
        int s;
        waitpid(-1, &s, 0); // Wait for child to close
    }
    else {
        //Check if there wass an error
        if(execvp(arr[0], arr) == -1){
            perror("Wrong command / Command doesn't exists"); 
            exit(errno);
        }   
    }
}

/*From main() -> splitInput() -> write in arr[]*/
void splitInput(char *input){
    i = 0;
    param = strtok(input, "\n ");
    while (param != NULL) { 
        arr[i++] = param; // Add param to arr
        param = strtok(NULL, "\n ");
    }
    arr[i] = NULL;
}

void about() {
    printf(" AUTHOR : TULCAN ANDRES \n");
    printf(" EMAIL : andres.tulcan02@e-uvt.ro\n");
    printf(" Code Language : C \n");
    printf(" Commands avalabile : wc / expand / env / clear / exit / help ( or -h )\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("clear");
    printf("andres@andres-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$> ");

    while(1)
    {
        //take input
        getline(&comd, &sizeLine, stdin);

        //Check input != empty
        if(strcmp(comd,"\n")==0){
            printf("andres@andres-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$> ");
            continue;
        }

        //Split input
        splitInput(comd);
        //printf("%s, arr 1 : ",arr[1]);

        //List commands
        if(!strcmp(arr[0], "exit") || !strcmp(arr[0], "quit"))
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        else if(!strcmp(arr[0],"help") || !strcmp(arr[0],"-h")){
            //MENU
            printf("\n getversion - print author and project informmations.\n");
            printf("\n wc - COMMAND \n");
            printf("\n -c         - print the characters number.");
            printf("\n -w         - print the word number.");
            printf("\n -l         - print the newline number.");
            printf("\n -L         - print the MAX. display width.\n");

            printf("\n EXPAND  - COMMAND \n");
            printf("\n -t         - have tabs N characters apart.");
            printf("\n -i         - dont convert tabs after non blanks.\n");

            printf("\n ENV     - COMMAND \n");
            printf("\n -u         - remove variable from the enviornment.");
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if(!strcmp(arr[0], "env")&& !strcmp(arr[1],"|") && arr[2]!="\0")
        {
            if(!strcmp(arr[2],"sort"))
            {
                extern char ** environ;
                char ** var;
                char str[50]="ENV_FOR_PROJECT=456";

                for(var=environ;*var!=NULL;var++)
                {
                    printf("\n %s", *var);
                }
            }
            else printf("no");
        }
        else
            run();
        printf("andres@andres-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$> ");
    }

    printf("\n///////////////\nError occured. Prob bug!!!\n/////////////////\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? (Also, that's not the way a shell / terminal / "OS class" is usually designed...)

Comment: The code is longer that this. I ve posted just a fragment for it. I know it s not the most efficient code you`ve ever seen. I want to sort the ENV alphabetically but i have dificulties with working with 2 pointers.

Comment: So the whole example code could be reduced to the part starting at `extern char ** environ`, wrapped in a stand-alone `main()`. Which would likely increase your chance at getting a good, focussed answer a hundredfold... and I would still ask, what is your *problem* with the code?

Comment: A shell does not implement all commands but forks processes to run external commands. To execute a pipe `env | sort` the shell would create a pipe, fork two processes for `env` and `sort`, connect `stdin` or `stdout` respectively to the ends of the pipe, close the unused pipe ends in all processes and `execvp` the external programs `env`  and `sort` in the child processes. A simple shell that implements commands with arguments and pipes only, can first split the command line into `|` and other text and then split every "other text" into command and arguments.

Comment: Are you asking about how to fork/exec a `env | sort` pipeline, or do you just want to sort the `extern char ** environ`?

Comment: SORT the extern char ** environ

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to sort alphabetically the env

Yes

1. Walk `environ` to find count of string pointers `n`.
2. Allocate an array `n` of string pointers `const char *a[n]`.
3. Copy `environ` into `a`.
4. Sort `a` with `qsort()`.
5. `printf()` the list `a`.
6. Free any allocations.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to sort alphabetically the env

Of course.

```
extern char ** environ;
```

[man environ](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html):

> The variable environ points to an array of pointers to strings called the "environment". The last pointer in this array has the value NULL.

So you can think of it as `char * environ[]`.

You don't want to *write* to this, so the first thing to do is to copy it -- for which you need to know how many entries there are.

```
size_t count = 0;

while ( environ[count] != 0 )
{
    ++count;
}
```

Now reserve the amount of space required for your copy (which, note, does not end on a NULL pointer as the original, but you have a count of elements now so the NULL pointer is not needed)...

```
char ** my_environ = malloc( sizeof( char * ) * count );
```

...make the copy...

```
memcpy( my_environ, environ, sizeof( char * ) * count );
```

...which you can then sort:

```
qsort( my_environ, count, sizeof( char * ), comp );
```

You need a compare function:

```
int comp( void const * lhs, void const * rhs )
{
    char const * l = *(char const **)lhs;
    char const * r = *(char const **)rhs;
    return strcmp( l, r );
}
```

And print:

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i )
{
    puts( my_environ[i] );
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd look for something other than "my own OS / Shell" as a programming project, as that is a much more complex problem than it first appears.